# KBN vs K tablebase for 10x10 board

Tags: endgame, tablebases

Where can I get the tablebase for king + bishop + knight versus king mate on 10x10 board?

Comment: <aol>metoo</aol> :-) I would even extend your question: Are there free tablebases with open code which can be embellished for n*n use, maybe even fairy pieces? BTW, I wouldn't stop at 10...Oh, and I never got one myself.

Comment: I have a related question that is not worth asking separately: until which n is KBN vs K on a n x n chessboard winning ?

Comment: @Evargalo winning within the 50 moves rule? Because otherwise I see no reason why it would not be winning anymore.